# onProgress with uploadData() method is giving progress update only once i.e. the final response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, azure-files

I'm using uploadData() method for uploading local file to azure file share.I'm facing issue with onProgress as I'm getting a single progress update i.e. the final update when file finally gets uploaded. Can some guide where I'm going wrong?

await fileClient.uploadData(selectedFile, {
rangeSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, // 4MB range size
parallelism: 20, // 20 concurrency
onProgress: ev => console.log(ev)
});

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/%40azure/storage-file-share_12.8.0/sdk/storage/storage-file-share/samples/javascript/advanced.js

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the limitation of underlying XMLHttpRequest API which doesn't support streaming, so the SDK only gets notified when download is finished.

Answer (score -1):

Azure Files offers fully managed file shares in the cloud that are accessible via the industry standard Server Message Block (SMB) protocol.

I checked some documents and blogs and found that the method is a parallel uploading method and it just sends a single request to Azure Storage server. **So if you want to get `onProgress` executed many times, I suggest you use the method `uploadStream`**. For more information check this [parallel uploading methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/storage-file-share-readme?view=azure-node-latest#following-features-interfaces-classes-or-functions-are-only-available-in-nodejs).

We can achieve Parallel uploading a Readable stream with ShareFileClient.uploadStream() in Node.js runtime as shown below.

```js
await fileClient.uploadStream(fs.createReadStream(localFilePath), fileSize, 4 * 1024 * 1024, 20, {
abortSignal: AbortController.timeout(30 * 60 * 1000), // Abort uploading with timeout in 30mins
onProgress: (ev) => console.log(ev)
});
console.log("uploadStream success");
```

Also read this [FileUploadStreamOptions interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-file-share/fileuploadstreamoptions?view=azure-node-latest) document for more information.

Comment: Thanks Saurav. But am working on browser runtime and can't use UploadSream() as it is not available in browser runtime.

Comment: @PriyanshuKumar Did you find out how to stream file/blob chunks from browser JS to Azure Blob Storage? blockBlobClient.uploadData(file as File) reports 0% 0% 0% 100% and it just doesn't want to stream file as chunks.